# You cannot create an inventory detail for this item. in suitescript

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

I am trying to create a bin transfer and trying to create inventory detail on the item, when I am using getCurrentSublistSubrecord({
                sublistId: 'inventory',
                fieldId: 'inventorydetail'
            });

I get this error "You cannot create an inventory detail for this item." Can you please help me with this??

Answer (score 2):

"You cannot create an inventory detail for this item" can be encountered when the item in the sublist is not a serial/lot numbered item or does not use bins or for the selected location the item doesn't have any inventory.

Answer (score 0):

"You cannot create an inventory detail for this item" is part of the advanced inventory management feature.
Retry the bin transfer but make sure the fields for **non-**serialised/lot numbered items are empty